# Drawing table view cell when drag and drop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have dragged an item into my tableview object.
When the dragged item hover over an item in tableview, 
the item is redrawn with selection background. The image is as under

[image]

The row of the tableview is not selected, when i checked selectedRow method.

My requirement is when an item hover any item i should control its selection 
and the background selection thereof.

Thanks,
iSight

Comment: Control it's selection? Do you mean you want to fire some method when you hoover over an item in your tableview? In that case I can help you. Please clearify your question better...

Comment: Ya that's right i want to control row selection of table view when hover around the row...

Comment: This answer should suffice for you. If you have any more questions let me know. Good luck!

Comment: I need in NSTableView. Sorry for not specific...

Comment: Ah, that explains. There should be a similar method in NSTableView then the one I posted below. Have you tried rowAtPoint: ?

Comment: Yes got the method rowAtpoint. You mean when the point is inside a row , I can make that row as selectable or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'control' the selection of a TableViewCell when 'hovering' over such an item you will have to call this method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
```

It's a method from the UITableView Class and uses the local coordinate system of your tableView. As is mentioned in the Apple Doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

When the method is called you will have a NSIndexPath returned. With it you can select the cell/item at that particular path.
Mind, selecting a path manually doesn't call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate-method so if you want a certain method called from that delegate you will have to do that manually as well!

This method is prolly called from the touchedDidMove method (where you also do the drag&drop) so getting the point needed for the method shouldn't be a problem for you.

You will figure it out :)
Good luck.